# find the value in arraylist using contains using asp.net?

Tags: arraylist

i am using a arraylist "**distincArray**" and i want to find the  current value inside the arraylist .
for that i have use the **contains** methods as below.I am still not able to find the element

```
if (distincArray.Contains(lblCompID.Text))
   {
    distincArray.RemoveAt(distincArray.IndexOf(lblCompID.Text));
   }
```

can any one help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to use the **Any** function.

```
distincArray.Any(x => x == lblCompID.Text)
```

Linq library is required

```
using System.Linq;
```